# Question about the comparison test for factorial series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges or diverges using only the comparison test (I am aware I can do this using the ratio test quiet easily).

The explanations I found were mostly:

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{3}{n}\cdot ... \cdot \frac{n}{n}\leq 
\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot1\cdot ... \cdot 1= \frac{2}{n^2}$$

My professor does this too:

[image]

My question is why do you keep the first two terms? In other words, why do you keep only the $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{2}{n}$? Why not keep $\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{2}{n}$,$\frac{3}{n}$ instead? Is there a reason that only the first two terms were kept? Thanks!

Comment: Simply put: because it works. $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, so “keeping the first two terms” is good enough to prove the convergence of your series. One term would not be sufficient because $\sum 1/n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k}{n^2}$ converges (indeed it is equal to $\frac{k\pi^2}{6}$). Therefore, if we can show that that $\frac{n!}{n^n} < \frac{k}{n^2}$ for some $k$, we have, by the comparison test, that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges too.

**So why do we take the first two terms?**

We cannot simply take the first term, because then our upper bound would be $\frac{1}{n}$. This is no good, since the harmonic series diverges. We have shown that that the proof works with the first two terms. The reason we didn't take the first three terms was that we simply didn't need to! You could have taken the first three terms, and the proof would have been equally as valid, but we might as well take the fewest terms necessary.